# How to check only all-categories checkbox or other remaing category checkboxes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

For example, if I check all-categories checkbox in given example all remaining checkboxes should be unchecked and if I check one or more remaining  category then all-category checkbox should be unchecked.

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7r2pV/293/)

HTML

```
 <div class="search-dropdown">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox all-categories" name="all-categories" id="all-categories" value="" /><label for="keys">All categories</label>
<hr>
<ul class="checkboxlist_list">
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox electical"  /><label>electrical</label><br/></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox mechanical" /><label>mechanical</label><br/></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox construction"/><label>construction</label><br/></li>
</ul>
</div>
<p class="category-holder">Select Category</p>
```

Javascript

```
    $('.search-dropdown input[type="checkbox"]').on("change", function(){
    var categories = [];
    $('.checkbox:checked').each(function(){        
        var category = $(this).next().text();
        categories.push(category);
    });
    $(".category-holder").html(categories.join(", "));
    if (!$(".category-holder").text().trim().length) {
    $(".category-holder").text("Select Category");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add these lines of code to your `change` event handler:

```
if($(this).is('.all-categories:checked')){
    $('.checkboxlist_list .checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    return $(".category-holder").text($(this).next().text());
}
$('.all-categories').prop('checked', false);
// ... the rest of your code ...
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ekgx03k1/5/)</kbd>

---

Optionaly (and even better), you can set all checkboxes to `:checked` and disable them when `.all-categories` checkbox is `:checked`

```
if($(this).is('.all-categories:checked')){
    $('.checkboxlist_list .checkbox').prop({'checked': 1, 'disabled' : 1});
    return $(".category-holder").text($(this).next().text());
}else if($(this).is('.all-categories')){
    $('.checkboxlist_list .checkbox').prop('disabled', 0);
}
// ... the rest of your code ...
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ekgx03k1/6/)</kbd>

Comment: if i check all-categories checkbox then all other checkboxes get selected which i don't want .

Comment: Ok, one moment :-) Just realized what you really want

Comment: how can i do with multiple checkboxes i mean to add all topics and other topics checkboxes

Comment: Could you make a HTML JSFiddle example?

Comment: it's ok to post it here

Comment: You should make the HTML a bit more *consistent*. Give each `<div>` section the same class (`.check-container`). Also each *select-all* checkbox should have the same class (`check-all`), so you can easily loop over http://jsfiddle.net/rj7z133L/

Comment: it works fine but can you make like first version . when i select all it should not check other checkboxes . like http://jsfiddle.net/ekgx03k1/5/

Comment: and [**this is why I like jQuery**](http://jsfiddle.net/rj7z133L/7/) (when I have fresh mind). Almost no need for minifying :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's in JS.

```
function checkAll(ele) {
 var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
 if (ele.checked) {
     for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
         if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
             checkboxes[i].checked = true;
         }
     }
 } else {
     for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
         console.log(i)
         if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
             checkboxes[i].checked = false;
         }
     }
 }
```

}

```
<input type='checkbox' name='select_all' onClick='javascript:checkAll(this)'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check if the current element clicked id is `all-categories`
And if it is, uncheck all checkboxes within `checkboxlist_list` class using `removeAttr():

```
if($(this).attr('id')=='all-categories'){
     $('.checkboxlist_list .checkbox').removeAttr('checked')
}
```